# How to get installed VisualStudio extensions programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio, envdte

How can I get a list of installed VisualStudio extensions? Somehow through `DTE`? Just the names would be fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help:

```cs
System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider = package as System.IServiceProvider;
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IVsExtensionManager em =
       (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IVsExtensionManager)serviceProvider.GetService(
            typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SVsExtensionManager));

    string result = "";
    foreach(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IInstalledExtension i in em.GetInstalledExtensions())
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IExtensionHeader h = i.Header;
        if (!h.SystemComponent)
            result += h.Name + " (by " + h.Author + ") v" + h.Version + " " + h.MoreInfoUrl + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

Copied from https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html #20.

Comment: Not sure how this can be the answer when it doesnt use the DTE.

Comment: why does it have to?

Comment: > Somehow through DTE?

Comment: That was a question not a request ;-) I think you misunderstood :-)

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility, if you don't want DTE, because you are not running from within Visual Studio or are concerned about performance you can query the extensions from the file system / registry:

**For User Extensions**
*%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio*.vsix*

**For General Extensions**
*\Common7\IDE\Extensions*.vsix*

IF you want to be 100% correct you can look up the paths in 
*\Common7\IDE\devenv.pkgdef*

**NOTE:** There can be additional paths in the *PkgDefSearchPath*.

To check wether a User Extensions is enabled or not you have to query the registry:
*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ExtensionManager\EnabledExtensions*

There are some other rules that apply, which you can find in this blog from Microsoft:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/19/how-vsix-extensions-are-discovered-and-loaded-in-vs-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Nice alternative. My question was not detailed enough, but I'll also need to know if the extension is enabled... Still voted up =)

Comment: I think `\Common7\IDE\devenv.pkgdef` should be `\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef`, at least on Visual Studio 2017. This will also show that you need `CommonExtensions` folder as well, which contains most Microsoft's common extensions (like language services) in VS 2017.