# Is there a way to check if a visual studio extension is installed FROM CODE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using a Visual Studio extension that lets me paste images on the code. This has been very useful for documenting the most copmlex parts of the project.

However, if you do not have the extension installed, you only see a comment in the code, with no clear indication that an extension is missing that would turn that coment into an image.

Is there a way I could either of the following?:
a) Install the extension automatically at build.
b) Add a warning at build time that says what is missing.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071771/how-to-get-installed-visualstudio-extensions-programmatically)? It might help.

Comment: Not sure. AFAICS, the solution you mentioned is to build extensions that can query for the installed extensions. Is it?

I see that I was a bit ambiguous in my question. With "code" I meant "declarative code". Basically, I would like to indicate in my project file that the extension XYZ is needed, and either automatically install it or at least show a message.

If I understood correctly, the solution you provided means that I would need to create an extension. But then, we just slid the problem further: How do I make sure that the new extension is installed when opening the project?